# Upgrading MVC server packages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I develop an MVC project in Visual Studio using a local instance of SQL Server and IIS. I'm now ready to push it to our test site but I can't get packages to work. I've upgraded nearly all of them so they need to be transferred to the server.

I tried copying the package DLLs to the `bin` directory on the server, same location as the project DLLs, but I'm getting the following error (it looks like it's trying to look in my local directory even though it's on the server). How do I correct this error?

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, /
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its /
dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not /
match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

In the details:

```
[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, /
Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one/
of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not /
match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
    ProjectName.Admin.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in /
    C:\Users\myUsername\Documents\ProjectName\Branches\Dev\Presentation\ProjectName.Admin\Global.asax.cs:117
```

Comment: Are you using the mvc nuget package? If so, publishing will include all of the assemblies you need.

Comment: @jrummell I'm using NuGet, yes. What do you mean by publishing? We deploy the site by building and manually copying the DLLs over, but if there's a better/easier way I'm definitely open to it.

Comment: This is normally a version issue with the assembly. Check the references version, and then look if its the same in packages.config and Web.config. Also, check to make sure any 3rd party DLLs aren't referencing the old MVC version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right click on your web project and click Publish, all of the required files will be deployed correctly.

[How to: Publish Web Application Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983453(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: What if you right on your project in the solution explorer?

Comment: I figured that out, which is why I deleted my initial comment. I'm now getting other errors with publishing (such as IIS saying "Access to the path is denied"), but I'm working through them. I'll accept this as an answer if this works.